# How to Increase a number in INDIRECT function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I need to increase the value referred to in `$C$1` at the end of the following formula while dragging down:

```
=INDIRECT("data!"&A$3&$C$1)
```

`A$3` refers to `A`, `$C$1` refers to `1`. And both `A$3`'s and `$C$1`'s values are changing on some conditions, that's why I have to keep them dynamic.

The following formula also gives the same result:

```
=INDIRECT("data!"&A$3&$C$1+0)
```

However, if I drag down it, the `0` at the end, still stays `0`. And if I manually change it to `1`, I get what I want.

So, I expect the following outputs for `$C$1 = 1`:

```
data!A1
data!A2
...
```

Anyone?

Comment: `=INDIRECT("data!"&A$3&$C$1+row($A1)-1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much, worked like a charm